# Flipping the boolean values in a list Python

Tags: python

I have a boolean list in Python

```
mylist  = [True , True, False,...]
```

which I want to change to the logical opposite `[False, False, True , ...]` 
Is there an inbuilt way to do this in Python (something like a call `not(mylist)` )  without a hand-written loop to reverse the elements?

Answer (score 114, accepted):

It's easy with list comprehension:

```
mylist  = [True , True, False]

[not elem for elem in mylist]
```

yields

```
[False, False, True]
```

Comment: _Is there an inbuilt way to do this in Python (something like a call not(mylist) ) without a hand-written loop to reverse the elements?_ ....... `for i in mylist` Hmmm...

Comment: @AMC, *any* list modification is going to be a loop under the covers, I *suspect* the OP just didn't want a multi-line explicit `for` loop which appended each element. A single-line list comprehension is very *much* the Pythonic way to do this.

Comment: @paxdiablo _A single-line list comprehension is very much the Pythonic way to do this._ Agreed.

Answer (score 55):

The unary tilde operator (~) will do this for a numpy.ndarray. So:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> mylist = [True, True, False]
>>> ~numpy.array(mylist)
array([False, False, True], dtype=bool)
>>> list(~numpy.array(mylist))
[False, False, True]
```

Note that the elements of the flipped list will be of type numpy.bool_ not bool.

Comment: While `numpy` is a nice package, I just worry sometimes about answers suggesting it's used in cases where the task can be done perfectly well in base Python.

Comment: @paxdiablo That is still useful to know that other solutions exist. If you need to flip thousands of values from a np.array, `~array` will be much faster than `[not b for b in array]`.

Comment: @Guimoute Not every question involving an array-like value needs to address the Numpy equivalent. This isn't a case where the OP should have been using `numpy` in the first place.

Answer (score 17):

```
>>> import operator
>>> mylist  = [True , True, False]
>>> map(operator.not_, mylist)
[False, False, True]
```

Comment: Maybe add a description of why this works? Generally an answer with only code isn't good practice.

Answer (score 15):

Numpy includes this functionality explicitly. The function
"numpy.logical_not(x[, out])" computes the truth value of NOT x element-wise.

```
import numpy
numpy.logical_not(mylist)
```

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.logical_not.html (with same examples)

Example:

```
import numpy
mylist  = [True , True, False]
print (mylist)
```

returns [True, True, False]

```
mylist=numpy.logical_not(mylist)
print (mylist)
```

returns [False False  True]

Comment: Am I the only one who doesnt understand a word of this explanation?

Comment: Numpy is doing it for you. I've added an example.

Comment: This is a good answer, but I would argue that list comprehension is a more "Pythonic" way to do this.

Answer (score 13):

numpy.invert is another nice option:

```
x = [False, True, True] 
not_x = np.invert(x) # [True, False, False]
```

Comment: What does numpy.invert do? How does it work? Documentation? Please add more details.

Answer (score 11):

Why not just use a simple list comprehension?

```
mylist[:] = [not x for x in mylist]
```

Comment: Just curious, is the [:] necessary in this case?

Comment: @Levon, the `[:]` means `mylist` is still referring to the same list. This may be desireable if the list is supposed to be mutated inside a function.

Comment: @gnibbler But the list comprehension is creating a new list, so is the only difference is that using [:] the memory location (id) of `mylist` wouldn't change while w/o it, it would?

Comment: @Levon it makes a difference if you have other variables referring to `mylist` - with the `[:]`, they will be affected; without it, they won't.

Comment: @lvc I just confirmed my assumption about id()/memory location that I mentioned to gnibbler by testing it in iPython. I can see your point, if some other object was pointing at `mylist` it would be important its address didn't change. Thanks.

Comment: @Levon, it's also possible to assign to a slice with a generator expression instead of a list comprehension

Comment: Let me see if I have this right. mylist[:] creates a nameless copy of the list, wherein each of the slots in the generic copy is the same memory address as in mylist. Then it's a simple case of multiple assignment, but the generic slots in the generic list each get the incoming value, which ends up overwriting the pointers in the original list. Is that right?

Comment: @GaryFixler kind of - although in Python, it tends to be a bad idea to try to think in terms of pointers and memory addresses. `mylist[:] = ...` is a slice assignment, which means it ends up calling `list.__setitem__` with a `slice` object - which removes all the items of `mylist` in that slice (in this case, all of it), and puts the RHS iterable into that spot. The important difference to your mental model is that the slice and the RHS don't have to be the same length: try `a = list(range(10)); a[2:4] = range(5)`.

Comment: @lvc Would be better to give that specific explanation about the `[:]` directly in your answer.

Answer (score 6):

I would do it the way everybody else is saying, but for sake of documenting alternatives, you could also do

```
import operator
myList = map(operator.not_, myList)
```

Answer (score 3):

what about the following

```
>>> import numpy
>>> list(numpy.asarray(mylist)==False)
```